# Getting the User Geopoint

Tags: android

I'm Trying to get the user geopoint with this code

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
               GeoPoint test = new GeoPoint((int)location.getLatitude()*1000000, (int)location.getAltitude()*1000000);
               MapView mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mvmap);
               MapController mapcontrol = mapview.getController();
               mapcontrol.animateTo(test);
               mapview.setStreetView(true);
               mapview.setSatellite(true);
                mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            }


            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

but I'm getting an error that says like this.

```
    07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.frux.kfcmobile/com.frux.kfcmobile.MapViewActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requested provider network doesn't exisit
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requested provider network doesn't exisit
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1429)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:646)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:660)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:482)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at com.frux.kfcmobile.MapViewActivity.onCreate(MapViewActivity.java:56)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
07-25 16:02:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(7262):     ... 11 more
```

can anyone can figure out what causing the error?

Comment: Have you added location permissions to the manifest?

Comment: here is what I added to my manifest                                       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: If network location is turned off in your OS settings. you won't be able to register a listener to it.

Comment: does this work in emulator? or I need to test it on a device?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you can only test the GPS provider in the emulator

Comment: it works but it didn't show my exact location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
GeoPoint test = new GeoPoint((int)location.getLatitude()*1000000, (int)location.getLongitude()*1000000);
```

instead of

```
 GeoPoint test = new GeoPoint((int)location.getLatitude()*1000000, (int)location.getAltitude()*1000000);
```

i.e. use `getLongitude()` instead of `getAltitude()`.

To show exact location use,

```
int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
          int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
          GeoPoint test= new GeoPoint(
        lat,lng);
```

It works for me.

Comment: I already change it to getLongitude but I still got the error

Comment: yes it works. but can I know your zoom level to show more specific location

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are using emulator for testing if yes you are getting exception here.

```
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

I dont think you can not test network provider on emulator.You can test it with gps like this

```
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Comment: You're correct, this is not possible with the emulator as of today.

Comment: You're right when I change the codes like what you say it works in my emulator. now I will test it on device to see if this is really working

Comment: @user1545096 yeah give it a try.

Comment: @user1545096 to make this work you have to take your device outside as GPS wont work indoor. or use this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ajeje.fakelocation application to fake location